# Linq average count by day of week

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get the total average count of row instances by day of week. So over the past year, I'm trying to get the average amount of rides that happened on a monday/tuesday/wed/ect.

Here's what I have so far.  That gives me the total count per day of week, but not the average count.

```
UnitOfWork.Query<WorkoutRecord>()
   .Where(x => x.WorkoutDate > baseDate)
   .GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", x.UploadDate))
   .Select(x => new AdminDashboardWorkoutsGroupedDay()
   {
       DayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)x.Key,
       WorkoutCount = x.Count()
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: in this case, `x` would be `IGrouping<DayOfWeek,WorkoutRecord>` so just `x.Average()` would not work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you well, in the end you're trying to get *one* number, the average count per weekday. This requires a second grouping that reduces the data to one group:

```
UnitOfWork.Query<WorkoutRecord>()
   .Where(x => x.WorkoutDate > baseDate)
   .GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", x.UploadDate))
   .Select(x => new AdminDashboardWorkoutsGroupedDay()
   {
       DayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)x.Key,
       WorkoutCount = x.Count()
   })
   .GroupBy(g => 0) // or g => "x", or whatever
   .Select (g1 => (decimal)g1.Sum(x => x.WorkoutCount) / g1.Count())
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked.  Thanks @Gert Arnold, you got me really close. I had to group by day and count all the workouts, then take the average of that grouping by weekday.

```
UnitOfWork.Query<WorkoutRecord>()
    .Where(x => x.WorkoutDate > baseDate && x.TotalTicks > 600)
    .GroupBy(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.UploadDate))
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Date = x.Key ?? DateTime.UtcNow,
        TheCount = x.Count()
    })
    .GroupBy(x=> SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", x.Date))
    .Select (x => new AdminDashboardWorkoutsGroupedDay()
    {
        WorkoutCount = (x.Average(y=>y.TheCount)),
        DayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)x.Key
    })
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear *what* property you want the average of, but assuming you have a property like `WorkoutRecord.Duration`, you should be able to get the average like:

```
UnitOfWork.Query<WorkoutRecord>()
    .Where(x => x.WorkoutDate > baseDate)
    .GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", x.UploadDate))
    .Select(x => new AdminDashboardWorkoutsGroupedDay()
    {
        DayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)x.Key,
        AverageDuration = x.Average(w => w.Duration)
    })
    .ToList();
```